# truncate text in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm working in this reactJS component and I want to know if reactJS has capabilities to filter string contents:

```
var Album = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup: function() {
  var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
  return { __html: rawMarkup };
},

render: function() {

  return (
    <div className='col s12 m6 l4'>
       <div className='card'>
         <div className='card-image'>
            <img  style={{minHeight:'220px', maxHeight:'220px' }} src={this.props.image} />
         </div>
         <div className='card-content' style={{minHeight:'100px', maxHeight:'100px'}}>
          <span style={{overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis'}}>             
             {this.props.name}
          </span>
         </div>
         <div className='card-action'>
         </div>
        </div>          
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

How can I truncate the text inside span tag??

regards

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this with CSS only ? (looking at your span's inlined styles)
React itself doesn't offer a way to truncate a string. You can call this.props.name.substring(0, n) to return a portion of a string.

Comment: you can use truncate method directly. React is only Javascript library, you can use language directly.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle example because as i know React doesn't allow you add space between html element, it automatically truncates these spaces. My [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29918/)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can pass the `prop` to function and return the truncated version:

```
...

<span style={{overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis'}}>             
    {this.truncate(this.props.name)}
</span>

...

truncate: function(str) {
    return str.length > 10 ? str.substring(0, 7) + "..." : str;
}
```

Comment: @daniels I've updated the answer to implement an example truncate function. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
{info.substring(0, 20)} {info.length >= 20 && '...'}
```

Comment: {mystring.substring(0, 20) } { mystring.length >= 20 && `...` }